# Lotus notes migration to oracle 11

Tags: oracle11g, lotus-notes, lotus

While migrating certain rich text fields from Lotus Notes to Oracle, I get migration results in some invalid characters. For example, a `'` becomes a `boxgEKOVESTboxh`. So how can we find out the code page of the Lotus Notes form and how to convert it to UTF8?

Answer (score 1):

All Lotus Notes data is stored in LMBCS. It's tough to find info about LMBCS. Here's a [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20050413000108/http://www.batutis.com/i18n/papers/lmbcs/index.html) via the Internet Archive's Wayback Machine to an old paper that describes it in detail. Also, here's a [link](http://www.openntf.org/Projects/codebin/codebin.nsf/CodeSearch/CE6B55B6B4A04A6E862576E10008B911) to an OpenNTF project that I contributed a few years ago, which contains documents organized into views to provide tables mapping Unicode to LMBCS.

Note, however, that while LMBCS is the storage format, some APIs and most tools for accessing Lotus Notes data perform automatic conversions. (E.g., the Notes Client itself running on a Windows computer automatically converts from LMBCS to Unicode in order to properly display characters.)  Without knowing a lot more about how you are doing your conversion to Oracle, what tools are involved, what APIs they use, and what environments they are runnning in (because autotomatic conversions are usually dependent on the settings of the environment) there is no way to know exactly what's going wrong.